# E-mails sobre recompensas chegando atrasados

Tags: bug, recompensa, notificações

Coloquei recompensas em 3 perguntas recentemente, e todos os lembretes de que as recompensas estavam prestes a expirar chegaram tarde demais. Hoje mesmo recebi mais um, referente à recompensa em [Como realmente aprender a usar promessas em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16921/como-realmente-aprender-a-usar-promessas-em-javascript), expirada há quase uma semana.

Comment: Tem vários problemas no sistema de notificação. Ele te avisa antes de expirar, e provavelmente você quer deixar mais tempo, aí entra em tolerância, aí não avisa mais e você esquece.